# How to change the URL of a Silverlight app using this strategy?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, url, web

I'm developing a Silverlight application without ASP.NET.

I'm using this simple strategy: http://jesseliberty.com/2008/05/31/multi-page-applications-in-silverlight/comment-page-1/

However, when I compile it, it will appear the url like this: www.mysite.com/MainPage.html

Is there any strategy using this ideia to change the Url depending on which xaml I am?

So if I go to Registration page, the url could change to this: www.mysite.com/Registration.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Navigation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. It's a solution, but I want using the strategy above =x. Not using Silverlight Application Page.